# How to get google plus contacts using google iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I want to get all of my google plus friends list. So I though of using google plus SDK. But it says :
(In red colour box shown in image) Google plus sign in is deprecated instead use google Sign-In SDK.

**Note :** (In blue box) They have mentioned that use Google Sign-In to allow users to sign in to your app when app doesn't need Google Plus features.

So my doubt is Which SDK should I use to get google Plus contacts ?

[image]

Comment: have you find any solution for this